# How do I decrease cell size to 280*35?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I need to decrease the table view cell of navigation controller to 280*35. I have tried to with `cgrect`, but it's not working...

How can I set it?

Answer (score 0):

The width of a UITableViewCell is always determined by the width of the UITableView that contains it.

You can change the height of your Cell by using UITableViews delegate message `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I perfectly understood that. Setting the width for the Table view to 280 is the only Way to Set the width of the Table Cell to 280. Why do you want to make it smaller? Perhaps an accessory View might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set row height programmatically, as tonclon pointed out, or, if all rows need to get the same height, set it in Interface Builder as a propery of the `UITableView`, in de Inspector window under the size tab. It says "height" right at the top, that's the row height.

This is easier and (presumably) faster.